# Install LAMP Stack on Debian Jessie - Packages not found

Tags: linux, debian, debian-jessie

I am trying to install the LAMP stack on my debian jessie server.

[image]

I tried the following to install LAMP:

```
apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-gd php7.0-opcache php7.0-json php7.0-mbstring php7.0-xml php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-cli php7.0-curl php7.0-zip php7.0-intl php7.0-soap php7.0-tidy
```

However, I get:

[image]

Any suggestions why the packages cannot be found?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Run apt update and try again?

Comment: @AravindVoggu Thx for your reply! I still get the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search if the package exists `aptitude search "libapache2-mod-php*"`

Not sure about debian, but 7.0 was not available in Ubuntu 17.x. Try installing 7.2 or 7.1 instead. Make sure to `apt update` before you start.

Try replacing 7.0 with the results from apt search. Or you can just forego the version numbers and install.